# Bootstrap footer panel stuck in middle of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having this problem with my footer it stuck in the middle of the page. But the weird thing is it doesn't happen on any other of my page.

I have tried different methods of approaching this and none of them work I'm all out of idea.

Any help would be great

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- fortawesome cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">  
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src = "logo.png" alt = "logo"> </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="watch.html">Watch</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Heros</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Stats</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<hr>
<div class = "container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8"> <div class = "TwitchPlayer">
<iframe id="player"  
  src="http://www.twitch.tv/starladder1/embed" >

  </iframe>
  </div></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><div class = "twitchChat">
<iframe  id="chat_embed" src="http://www.twitch.tv/starladder1/chat"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="panel panel-footer">
  <div class="panel-body"><div class="footerRow-row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"> <a href = "" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-lg btn-linkedin" target="_blank">
    <span class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></span>
  </a></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
</script><p>© </p></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><a href = "" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-lg btn-github" target="_blank">
    <span class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></span>
  </a></div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so we can see how your code is rendering. This block of code is difficult to read and we cannot see your CSS which makes it very difficult to see what is wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry Im kinda new this, I have uploaded it to fiddle, it won't load in the twitch player or chat. But hopefully you see whats happening [link](https://jsfiddle.net/27p7zv1y/)

Comment: Well i see that the footer is up close to the navbar but this is only because there is no content between the nav and the footer. If i add a height to the `container` div then the footer drops down to the bottom of that and if it goes past the height of the page it goes to the bottom. there is a `margin-bottom: 20px` attributed to the footer which is keeping it from hitting the bottom completely but it is acting like it should otherwise. Maybe post a screenshot of the problem in your question?

Comment: Oh I feel stupid now it's obvious. Adding the height to the container did the job.

Thanks :)

Comment: ok ill make my comment an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/27p7zv1y/1/).

The footer seems to be acting normally. In your fiddle it is staying in the middle because there is no content between the nav and the footer. When I add a height to the `container` the footer drops down and stays at the bottom of the page.

Glad I could help!